# DotnetBrowser report an error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACH_READ_FAILURE"

Tags: c#, wpf, dotnetbrowser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgSY4.png)
In the process of use, there is a certain probability of this problem

Deleting the cache directory can solve this problem, but deleting the user information is not a good solution, there is no way to solve this problem without deleting the cache directory

Comment: Please extend your question with the DotNetBrowser version. In addition, please specify how you configure the user data directory for DotNetBrowser. Do you use a folder inside the user's temporary directory for this purpose?

Comment: the version is 2.9.0,The specified DotNetBrowser configuration user data directory is a folder in the user's temporary directory;

Comment: Consider specifying a custom user data directory located outside the temporary directory to make sure its contents will not be deleted occasionally. The cache is also stored inside the user data directory.